# simple functions

Tags: functions

[function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtvLK.jpg)

${(2,4)(-8,9)}$ is a set of number for $f(x)$

$f(x) -> px + q$

$2p + q = 4$

$-8p + q = 9$

$10p = -5$

$p = -2$

I only get $p$, but I wasn't sure whether correct or not. Help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error: $10p = -5$ doesn't yield $p = -2$.  Divide both sides by $10$ to get the correct value of $p$.  Then you can use $2p+q = 4 \to q = 4-2p$ to obtain the value of $q$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a easier way to solve it.

If you take the slope of the two lines using m=change in y/change in x 
you get (9-4)/(-8-2) which is -1/2. So, you have y=-1/2x+q. Take a point and insert it to solve. Let's use (2,4). You have 4=-1/2(2)+q. So q=5. So your answer is y=-1/2x+5

If we were to go that way, you did it almost right, but -5/10 isn't -2 it's -1/2. Then, you would insert it and solve. Let's use 2p+q=4. It would be 2(-1/2)+q=4. If you solve, you get q=5. So, your equation is y=-1/2x+5